# Why toolbar is not hiding while scroll?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am using Toolbar and more than one Textview with some text,but when i scroll i am trying to  hide my toolbar but its not hiding,following is my xml code can anyone help me with this,Thanks in advance..

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:paddingTop="24dp">



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Product Name:"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/desc_prodname"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Brand:"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/desc_brandnm"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description:"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/desc_description"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum"

                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Price:"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/desc_price"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category:"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/desc_catname"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Subcategory:"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/desc_subcatname"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

                />






        </LinearLayout>




    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"/>-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help? https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

You can just observe the scrolled area and show/hide the toolbar when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Put you toolbar inside "NestedScrollView"

Comment: scrollview canb host only one child

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

**Explanation** : 
The scroll flag used within the attribute `app:layout_scrollFlags` must be enabled for any scroll effects to take into effect.

For more information and different scrolling effects check [Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#responding-to-scroll-events)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that without using any libraries, you have to put Toolbar inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout. Here is the working layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar>

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

// put your contents here..

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```